# Aggregate SQL Function to grab only one from each grouping

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2000

I have a table that I need to normalize with many fields In **SQL-Server 2000**.
It contains 2 fields which I'm using to come up with distinct combination as defined by the specs. 
ID and Rate: there are multiple rows of same IDs and Rates

I first created a temp table by grouping the IDs and Rates combination.

```
SELECT ID, Count(*) AS IDCounts, SUM(RATE) As Total 
INTO #Temp
GROUP BY ID
```

Now I use Distinct to find only the unique combinations. So i'll have multiple ID groups sharing same Total and IDCounts

```
SELECT DISTINCT Total, IDCounts
INTO #uniques
FROM #Temp
```

Now my question is how to join a single ID back to that distinct grouping of IDCounts and Total and put that into a new table? It doesn't matter which one of the IDs in the groups as long as I use one from the same grouping.

Comment: why is question tagged 2k5 if you want 2K solutions?

Comment: Why does SQL Server 2000 imply no T-SQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keeping your temp tables (although this could all be done in a single query):

```
SELECT ID, Count(*) AS IDCounts, SUM(RATE) As Total 
INTO #Temp
GROUP BY ID

SELECT Total, IDCounts, MIN(ID) AS SomeID
INTO #uniques
FROM #Temp
GROUP BY Total, IDCounts
```

Answer (score 2):

Add "Min(ID) AS FirstID" to the select into #uniques.

Answer (score -1):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT MAX(ID) AS Id, Count(*) AS IDCounts, SUM(RATE) As Total 
FROM SOMETABLE
GROUP BY IDCounts, Total
```